# Does ImageReader convert surfaces to specified formats?

Tags: java, android, image

My app has an ImageReader that is configured for the JPEG format. I draw to the reader's surface a circle shape with its canvas. On the `OnImageAvailable` callback method, I grab the Image with `image = acquireNextImage()` and when I try to invoke

```
ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
```

I'm met with a huge crash dump (doesn't tell me anything meaningful). It works completely fine when I set the format to `PixelFormat.RGBA8888` and invoke the same call.